# Create a Flask Search Bar that Inserts URI Variable with url_for()

Tags: python, forms, flask

I have a Flask site that has a 'search bar' where you type in the location ID of a particular location and then click `Submit` to be taken to the page for that location, if it exists. Here's the current form action:

`<form id="locationinfo" action="{{ url_for('location') }}">`

When you click `Submit` you are taken to `/location?info=SITEID` and that works just fine. What I want to do is change this behavior slightly so that when a user clicks `Submit` they are taken to `/location/SITEID/` instead. I have the decorator set up in my main Flask routes file, but I'm struggling to put the pieces together to get this simple form together.

```
@app.route("/location/<locationid>/")
def locations(locationid):
    ...
    return locationid
```

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

[Edit with current full form code]

```
@app.route("/location")
    def location():
        location_id = request.args.get("info")
```

---

```
<form id="info" action="{{ url_for('location') }}">
    <input type="text" name="info" id="locationfield">
    <button type="submit">Go!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change how HTML forms submit their fields, they will always be in the query string or body (POST). One option is to use JavaScript to override the submit event to perform your own submit and re-render with the results.

A simpler solution is to redirect to the nice url after submit. This keeps the "search" action separate from the "show" action (even if they are handled by the same view).

```
@app.route('/location/')
@app.route('/location/<int:id>/')
def location(id=None):
    # redirect to the second form if the id wasn't in the path
    # raises 400 error if id wasn't in the query
    if id is None:
        return redirect(url_for('location', id=request.args['info']))

    # id is in the path, continue
    ...
```

You can expand this later if you want to search by something besides id. Perform the search then redirect to the found id.